# Problema al usar funcion header() en php

Tags: php, mvc

Buenas días colegas!

tengo un problema al usar header() en php, les cuento estoy usando mvc de manera nativa y el dashboard de mi app lo uso en el construct de mi clase template y es llamado desde el index por ende siempre es invocado!

la cosa es que estoy usando header("Location:'.URL.'Login.php"); para cuando se destruye la sesión y redireccionar al login pero me da este error!

**Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/Centralapp/Views/Template/Template.php:75) in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/Centralapp/Controller/PrincipalController.php** on line **46**

**Warning**:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/Centralapp/Views/Principal/Logout.php): failed to open stream: No existe el archivo o el directorio in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/Centralapp/config/Enrutador.php** on line **28**

**Fatal error**:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Centralapp/Views/Principal/Logout.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/Centralapp/config/Enrutador.php** on line **28**

los ultimos dos errores es porque no encuentra el archivo pero no existe ya que es una funcion del controlador! el primer error es el que me causa problemas!

el codigo de mi index es el siguiente:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
 define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DS);
 define('URL', 'http://localhost/Centralapp/');
 require_once "config/Autoload.php";

 if(@$_SESSION['InicioSesion'] == 'Si') {

 config\Autoload::run();
 require_once 'Views/Template/Template.php';
 config\Enrutador::run(new config\Request());
 }else{

 config\Autoload::run();
 require_once 'Login.php';
 config\Enrutador::run(new config\Request());

 }
```

el codigo de la funcion del controlador es el siguiente

```
 public function Logout(){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.URL.'Login.php');

}
```

llama a esa funcion porque en el template del dashboard tengo un boton para salir de la sesion y en ese enlace por la ruta llamo al metodo logout que es el que termina la sesión.

espero haberme explicado bien! Y gracias de ante manos saludos

Comment: ¿Ya probaste con `header('Location:Login.php');` ?

Comment: si pero me pide la ruta completa ya que por url lo que hace la app es pagina.cl/perro/ladra, donde perro es la clase y ladrar es la funcion y lo que venga posterior a ladrar lo toma como argumento de la funcion (si esque viene) por ende no puedo solo poner header('Location:login.php')

Comment: la función `header`es normalmente relativa a la página donde te encuentras de modo que si estas en pagina.cl/perro/ladra.php y quieres ir a login.php no es necesario proporcionar la ruta completa, sino sólo el nombre del archivo al que quieres accesar. Si de pagina.cl/perro/ladra.php quisieras ir a pagina.cl/gato/maulla.php tendrías que escribir `header('Location:../gato/maulla.php');`

Comment: El primer mensaje no es un en error, es una advertencia (Warning). Ese tipo de advertencias vienen dadas por lo general cuando usas `header` en dos partes distintas, o cuando intentas sacar algo por pantalla antes de `header`. Ten en cuenta que **absolutamente nada debe salir por pantalla antes de usar `header`. El warning dice que en la línea 75 del archivo  `Template.php` usaste ya `header`, y luego, vuelves a usarlo en la línea 46 de `PrincipalController.php`. Es un problema de organización en el flujo de tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano ahaha entiendo tiene sentido mira lo voy a revisar lo mas probable es que sea eso! tambien la app alojada en el hosting me da el siguiente warning:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cce37648/public_html/Centralapp/Login.php:1) in /home/cce37648/public_html/Centralapp/Controller/PrincipalController.php on line 45

no entiendo eso de "Login.php:1" ese 1 que significa?

Comment: Pablo ese `1` es la línea donde ocurre el Warning, el Error, o lo que sea. Te recomiendo que hagas un diseño MVC en el cual lleves un control estricto de lo que sale por pantalla. Podrías tener una clase dedicada a manejar la vista (View) que sea la única que tenga potestad de sacar información de tu aplicación. De ese modo te evitarás este tipo de trances. Todos esos errores o advertencias son por lo mismo, porque tu código no está ordenado y controlado adecuadamente y porque *alguien* está haciendo algo que no le corresponde hacer. Por ejemplo, un *controlador*  no debería nunca imprimir...